# Simple manipulation on large data frame in r

Tags: r, merge, bigdata

I have a relatively large data frame. It contains roughly 40 million rows and 12 columns, please see part of it below. Specifically, it is a 3-hr averaged ozone data for counties in the US. Each row represents a certain county and a certain day (from 19800101 to 20161231 for 3108 counties). Note that this data file has a size of 7.05 GB.

```
 index       date state.fips county.fp   X07.30   X10.30   X13.30   X16.30   X19.30   X21.30   X01.30   X04.30
1 01001 1980-01-01         01       001 29.98488 29.47778 29.12294 29.98976 31.69830 31.56405 30.48744 29.62118
2 01001 1980-01-02         01       001 29.03014 28.75464 28.58736 30.26555 32.39263 32.43746 31.70940 31.14960
3 01001 1980-01-03         01       001 30.69475 30.19832 29.68841 30.28920 31.61882 31.43047 31.01369 30.58366
4 01001 1980-01-04         01       001 30.20852 29.69874 29.47550 30.55639 32.62610 34.47959 35.54881 35.78104
5 01001 1980-01-05         01       001 35.80190 35.69129 35.89026 38.51287 39.82833 39.49016 38.73464 38.09185
6 01001 1980-01-06         01       001 37.32787 36.55899 35.96070 36.62670 37.03226 36.71239 35.86387 35.05945
```

The question is times in the columns below are in UTC, and I need to convert to US local time. There are five time zones for the US, namely Eastern time zone, Central time ozone, Mountain time zone, and Pacific time zone. Yes I only covered the contiguous US. How should I start this manipulation?

Also please pay attention that the original data file is large (7.05 GB). We may encounter no enough memory errors. I am working on a laptop with 16 GB RAM.

Below I post my code for doing this. However I don't how to add the `dplyr:case_when` to adjust time zones.

```
names(ozone) <- gsub("^X","", names(ozone)) # get rid of X in columns names

ozone <- pivot_longer(ozone, cols = c('01.30','04.30','07.30',
                                     '10.30','13.30','16.30','19.30','21.30'),
                                   names_to = 'time', values_to = 'ozone_val')

ozone$date <- ymd(ozone$date) # convert to date format

ozone$date = as.POSIXct(paste(ozone$date, ozone$time),
                             format = "%Y-%m-%d %H.%M",
                             tz = 'UTC')
ozone$date <- with_tz(ozone$date, "America/New_York") # how to apply case_when here

ozone$time <- substr(ozone$date, 12, 19)

ozone$year.day <- substr(ozone$date, 1, 10)

ozone <- subset(ozone, select = -date)

ozone_1 <- pivot_wider(ozone, id_cols = c('index','state.fips','county.fp','year.day'),
                     names_from = 'time', values_from = 'ozone_val')
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What code are you running that gives this error? Clearly it can't be reading the data frame itself. Perhaps if you post the code that produces the error we might be able to help?

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you working on a laptop / desktop / server? Do you know how much RAM you have?

Comment: I am working on a laptop with 16 GB RAM. The combined datafile has a size of 7.05 GB.

Comment: I updated my post.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started but you'll need to post a more complete reproducible example and/or some more info about what exactly you are looking for. But, you should be able to use this general framework if you do not run out of memory (e.g., you may be able to use something like `dplyr::case_when()` to create the timezone based on the state; or subsetting after making the column POSIXct). Hope this gets you started!

Also, I am happy to explain anything that is unclear!

```
library(data.table)

setDT(data)

names(data) <- gsub("^X", "", names(data))

dt <- melt(data, id.vars = c("index", "date", "state.fips", "county.fp"),
           variable.name = "time", value.name = "ozone_val")

dt[, date := as.POSIXct(paste(as.character(date), time), 
                        format = "%Y-%m-%d %H.%M",
                        tz = "America/New_York")]
print(dt, nrows = 10)

   index                date state.fips county.fp  time ozone_val
 1:  1001 1980-01-01 07:30:00          1         1 07.30  29.98488
 2:  1001 1980-01-02 07:30:00          1         1 07.30  29.03014
 3:  1001 1980-01-03 07:30:00          1         1 07.30  30.69475
 4:  1001 1980-01-04 07:30:00          1         1 07.30  30.20852
 5:  1001 1980-01-05 07:30:00          1         1 07.30  35.80190
---                                                               
44:  1001 1980-01-02 04:30:00          1         1 04.30  31.14960
45:  1001 1980-01-03 04:30:00          1         1 04.30  30.58366
46:  1001 1980-01-04 04:30:00          1         1 04.30  35.78104
47:  1001 1980-01-05 04:30:00          1         1 04.30  38.09185
48:  1001 1980-01-06 04:30:00          1         1 04.30  35.05945
```

**Data**:

```
data <- read.table(header = T, text = "index       date state.fips county.fp   X07.30   X10.30   X13.30   X16.30   X19.30   X21.30   X01.30   X04.30
1 01001 1980-01-01         01       001 29.98488 29.47778 29.12294 29.98976 31.69830 31.56405 30.48744 29.62118
2 01001 1980-01-02         01       001 29.03014 28.75464 28.58736 30.26555 32.39263 32.43746 31.70940 31.14960
3 01001 1980-01-03         01       001 30.69475 30.19832 29.68841 30.28920 31.61882 31.43047 31.01369 30.58366
4 01001 1980-01-04         01       001 30.20852 29.69874 29.47550 30.55639 32.62610 34.47959 35.54881 35.78104
5 01001 1980-01-05         01       001 35.80190 35.69129 35.89026 38.51287 39.82833 39.49016 38.73464 38.09185
6 01001 1980-01-06         01       001 37.32787 36.55899 35.96070 36.62670 37.03226 36.71239 35.86387 35.05945")
```

Comment: I updated my post. Two quick questions. Why you melt the data frame first? Can you provide a complete code with `case_when`? I guess it would be `tz = case_when(state.fips %in% eastern, "American/New_Your")` where `eastern` is predefined list of states in Eastern time zone. Am I right?

Comment: Following your code, I updated my code. Please help to refine my code as I have a very large data file. Thanks!

Comment: Hey @YabinDa, quick question. Are the times in the column names UTC or local??

Comment: Hey @Andrew those times in the column are UTC times. I need them to be local time. I found the `with_tn` command to perform the manipulation. My concern is how to do this in more efficient way considering the large data file. If you need more info, please let me know. Thanks!